# Two elements on top of each other with their parent's height adjusting to the larger one of them

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a nice way to do this?

So far I've tried flexbox, thinking that setting flex to children and absolute positioning the last child whilst setting top to 0 might do it, but no success.

A Chrome only (last version) solution would do.

```css
/*
  Height of .child-a and .child-b is dynamic,
  div with "more content" must be always under .parent,
  whether .child-a or .child-b is taller.
*/

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.parent > div {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-a {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}

.child-b {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-a"></div>
  <div class="child-b"></div>
</div>

<div>
  more content
</div>
```

(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoXRwV)

Comment: If both children have dynamic height and they must overlap; use JS / jQuery to calculate height of both and set on parent whichever is large.

Comment: @MohammadUsman I guess I could use javascript, but I kind of hoped there might be a css only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what I think I've got it, using css grid. Not the most elegant thing ever, but appears to work.
Gonna post it here in case somebody stumbles upon the same problem.

```css
.parent {
 width: 100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto;
 grid-template-rows: max-content;
}

.parent > div {
  width: 100%;
}


.child-a {
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.child-b {
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-a">aa</div>
  <div class="child-b">bb</div>
</div>

<div>
  more content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .parent {
  display: block;
}

.parent > div {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-a {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  height: 50px;
}

.child-b {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was my code before I've tried the flexbox thing, it doesn't work (at least in Chrome, haven't tried other browsers, but it shoudn't work elsewhere too).